# Try to guess a closed form expression .

Tags: sequences-and-series, polynomials

The first 4 terms of the sequence are:

> \begin{align} 
> P_0 &= \frac{1}{B+1} \\
> P_1 &= \frac{B^2+B+\alpha^2}{(B+1)^3} \\
> P_2 &= \frac{2B^4+4B^3+4B^2\alpha^2 +2B^2+4B\alpha^2+\alpha^4}{2(B+1)^5} \\
> P_3 &= \frac{6B^6+18B^5+18B^4\alpha^2+18B^4+36B^3\alpha^2+6B^3+9B^2\alpha^4+18B^2\alpha^2+9B\alpha^4+\alpha^6}{6(B+1)^7} 
> \end{align}

Note that this sequence could be reduce to:
$$P_n = \frac{B^n}{(B+1)^n}$$ 
if one take $\alpha=0$ and,
$$P_n = \frac{\alpha^{2n}}{n!}$$
if one set $B = 0$.

Is there a way to guess a closed form expression for this sequence?

For those who are familiar with quantum physics, $P_n$ is obtained when I was calculating the photon number statistics of a displaced thermal state. Where $B$ is the thermal photon number and $\alpha$ is the displacement amplitude.

Comment: I don't notice a great pattern in numerator though but the denominator certainly has a great pattern $$P_n=\frac {\cdots}{n! (B+1)^{2n+1}}$$ The problem with numerator is that it is not homogeneous and not even somewhat symmetric to observe

Comment: Hey can you please check if $$P_4= \frac {[24B^4(B+1)^4+\alpha ^2\{\alpha^6+16\alpha^4B(B+1)+32\alpha^2B^2(B+1)^2+64B^3(B+1)^3\}]}{24(B+1)^9}$$

Comment: Hello Manthanein. Unfortunately, your expression for P4 seems incorrect. According to my calculation:P4 = 24*B^8 + 96*B^7 + 96*B^6*alpha^2 + 144*B^6 + 288*B^5*alpha^2 + 96*B^5 + 72*B^4*alpha^4 + 288*B^4*alpha^2 + 24*B^4 + 144*B^3*alpha^4 + 96*B^3*alpha^2 + 16*B^2*alpha^6 + 72*B^2*alpha^4 + 16*B*alpha^6 + alpha^8

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The numerator is 
$$\sum_{k=0}^n c_k(B^2+B)^k\alpha^{2(n-k)}$$ where the sequences $c_k$ are
$$1\\
1,1\\
1,4,2\\
1,9,18,6\\
1,16,72,96,24$$
which are
$$\frac{(n!)^2}{((n-k)!)^2k!}$$